# Play video while downloading in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

This functionality seems to be common to most android players but how do you actually implement this? Say you have an http link to the mp4 file you want to play. How do you implement it in Android? Have read the following SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715674/play-video-while-downloading-on-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012422/video-streaming-by-getting-bytes-in-buffer-storage-and-play-it-while-downloading) but I have no idea what it means or how to implement it.

So far what I did was just this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileUrl), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks and good day!!

Comment: another tumbleweed question.sad. :(